# How to sort a dataframe horizontally based on the values of some columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe of the marks score by students

```
name | math | science | literature
----------------------------------
tom  | 89   | 97      | 53
nick | 61   | 71      | 67
barry| 83   | 79      | 73
```

For each student, based on the marks score, I want to know the strongest and weakest, middle and weakest subject as shown in the expected output dataframe as shown below

```
name | subject1    | subject2       | subject3
-----------------------------------------------------
tom  | science     | math           | literature
nick | science     | literature     | math           
barry| math        | science        | literature
```

**Question**: How can I do this in Python?

My current approach is manually comparing the marks of each of the three subjects with the other two subjects and and determining the right order as a list for each student and then creating a data frame from these lists. However this approach is not scalable as no. of combinations to check increases as the no. of subject increases. I am looking for a easy way to do this which will work with up to 10 subjects.

**Note**: If two subjects have the same score then to avoid ambiguity the subject1 will be the one which come first in alphabetical order

**Update 20-Aug-2022**: I get an error with the suggested solution

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, with the dataframe given

```
        math    science literature
name            
tom     89      97      53
nick    61      71      67
barry   83      79      73
```

We can take the values and use numpy to get the sorted indices with argsort

```
#The negation (-) is necessary because argsort sorts ascending by default
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.argsort(-df.values,axis=1), columns=['subject1','subject2','subject3'], index=df.index)

df1
        subject1    subject2    subject3
name            
tom     1           0           2
nick    1           2           0
barry   0           1           2
```

Then we can map the values back with the original

```
df1=df1.replace(dict(enumerate(df.columns)))

df1
        subject1    subject2    subject3
name            
tom     science     math        literature
nick    science     literature  math
barry   math        science     literature
```

Comment: I get an error while trying to implement your suggested solution. It complains about the negation (-) sign. If I remove it and just to see if it work, then it gives a different error. How did you run this?

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: With the - sign, I get the error as shown in the above screenshot. WIthout the - sign, I get "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: Use `set_index` to set `name` as the index. The issue is there's no such thing as `-(Tom)`